# How to make a method synchronous in scala?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, websocket

In this method I would like to see the actual response (result.toJson.toString or StatusCodes.InternalServerError.toString) returned instead of empty string. How can I do that?

```
def process(msgIn : WebSocketMessageIn, service : ActorRef) : String = {
  import model.Registration
  import model.RegistrationJsonProtocol._

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)

  msgIn.method.toUpperCase match {
    case "POST" =>
      log.debug(s"Handing POST message with body ${msgIn.body}")
      val registration = msgIn.body.convertTo[Registration]
      val future = (service ? PostRegistrationMessage(registration)).mapTo[Registration]
      var response = ""
      future onComplete {
        case Success(result) =>
          response = result.toJson.toString

        case Failure(e) =>
          log.error(s"Error: ${e.toString}")
          response = StatusCodes.InternalServerError.toString
      }
      response

    case "PUT" =>
      s"Handing PUT message ${msgIn.body}"
  }
}
```

Here is the code snippet that calls the method and sends the response to websocket

```
case Message(ws, msg, service) =>
  log.debug("url {} received msg '{}'", ws.getResourceDescriptor, msg)
  val wsMessageIn = msg.parseJson.convertTo[WebSocketMessageIn]
  val response = process(wsMessageIn, service)
  ws.send(response);
```

UPDATE 1: Updated to use Await.result(future, 5000 millis) instead of 'future onComplete { ... }'. Here is code snippet that changed. Works now, but just wondering how we will handle failures.

```
msgIn.method.toUpperCase match {
  case "POST" =>
    log.debug(s"Handing POST message with body ${msgIn.body}")
    val registration = msgIn.body.convertTo[ADSRegistration]
    val future = (service ? PostADSRegistrationMessage(registration)).mapTo[ADSRegistration]
    val response = Await.result(future, 5000 millis)
    response.toJson.toString
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Await.result`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.2/index.html#scala.concurrent.Await$@result[T](awaitable:scala.concurrent.Awaitable[T],atMost:scala.concurrent.duration.Duration):T) which is blocking. Something like this:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
val result = Await.result(future, atMost = 10.second)
val response = //result processing
```

Just the same, you could pass the future back and perform the `send` in the `onComplete` which would be much more reactive

Comment: Changed the code to 

    response = Await.result(future, 5000 millis)
    response

Getting this compilation error

    [error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[model.Registration]
    [error]  required: scala.concurrent.Awaitable[String]
    [error]         response = Await.result(future, 5000 millis)

Comment: Can you post your new code to verify, however looking at the error, I am guessing that you are trying to set the result to response, whereas result will return a Registration. I did not know the type well, so that is why I just put the comment....my guess is that it should be result(...).toJson.toString

Comment: Thanks. Removed the onComplete block and added Await, it works now. Posted the updated code in question. However, I was wondering how we can handle timeouts and failures now. Any idea?

Comment: You could use a Try -> http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.util.Try